# deploy minmal python installation and packages with custom installer

Tags: python, windows, pip

I use a [WiX Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/) installer to distribute my C# application for Windows. Now I have integrated pyhton scripts for some data processing and therefore I need to distribute a python installation including the required dependencies.

So i took a [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/) minimal (dot) distribution, picked only the containing python folder, cleared that of unused stuff (Doc, include, libs, tcl, Tools) and added it to my installer.

**Is it feasible to ship a cleared out WinPython with my installer?** (from a technical and a legal perspective)

**How can i ship dependencies for offline installation?**

Right now I use pip. I added .whl files downloaded with `python.exe -m pip download` to the installer and then perform an offline installation with `python.exe -m pip install --no-index --find-links=...` in my installer.

Could I also just install everything into my minimal python using pip and then deliver that via installer to other machines?